# react-native-device-info getPhoneNumber return null

Tags: react-native

I am a newbier to andorid developer and react-native-device-info.
when i use react-native-device-info function DeviceInfo.getPhoneNumber() for getphonenumber,but it return nothing, when i goto the deviceinfo.d.ts find getPhoneNumber() undefined, my react-native-device-info is "version": "0.12.1"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JO9UB.png)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you just need to update your AndroidManifest.xml, adding this permission ?

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>`

Source: https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info#permissions

Comment: i have been add READ_PHONE_STATE READ_PHONE_NUMBERS READ_SMS

Comment: it works in my avd,get phonenumber but in real phone xiaomi MAX-2 do not works,it return empty string, now i will do this in another phone